# T-SQL Order by doesn't work with Cast in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, sql-order-by

Can't seem to get the order by to work with cast. Can someone help?

Error message is:

> Invalid column name NewPrice

```
Select top 100 ma.*,
               (Select Top (1) Price from [dbo].[ItemSKU] Where ma.OldSku = NewSKu) as NewPrice
from [dbo].[2018] as ma
order by cast (NewPrice as decimal(10,2)) desc
```

Comment: Does it work without the cast? In this case I would suggest do put the cast into the subquery...?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the scope of the column. You introduce column at the same time as you are using it. It's not allowed in SQL Server.

To be clear - you can use alias of an column in an `ORDER BY`, but the issue here is that you are using it inside `CAST` function - that's the problem.

Right syntax would be (this solution is by changing the scope):

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM (
    SELECT ma.*,
           (SELECT TOP (1) Price FROM [dbo].[ItemSKU] WHERE ma.OldSku = NewSKu) AS NewPrice
    FROM [dbo].[2018] AS ma
) a ORDER BY CAST(NewPrice AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC
```

or (here we do all operations needed to order in column list, so you can reference aliased column in an `ORDER BY`)

```
SELECT TOP 100 ma.*,
       CAST((SELECT TOP (1) Price FROM [dbo].[ItemSKU] WHERE ma.OldSku = NewSKu) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS NewPrice
FROM [dbo].[2018] AS ma
ORDER BY NewPrice
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` can reference columns produced by arbitrary expressions in the `SELECT` since it's logically processed after it. The usual problem is people trying to reference `SELECT` columns in `WHERE`, but that's not happening here. If it was just about "scope", `ORDER BY NewPrice` would also fail, but it does not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right, but the real issue here is placing that column in `CAST` function, that produces error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a subtle problem.  As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) explains:

> Specifies a column or expression on which to sort the query result
>   set. A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias, or a
>   nonnegative integer representing the position of the column in the
>   select list.

What is left out is that the *expression* could use a column alias.  That is subtle, but a limitation (and one not present in most other databases).

I think the simplest solution is to do the `cast()` in the subquery.  If you want to order by the value, isn't that what you want to see?

```
Select top 100 ma.*,
       (Select Top (1) cast(i.Price as decimal(10, 2))
        from [dbo].[ItemSKU] i
        Where ma.OldSku = i.NewSKu
       ) as NewPrice
from [dbo].[2018] ma
order by NewPrice desc;
```

Notice that I also added table aliases and qualified column names into the query.  This is a best practice whenever your query refers to more than one table.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting NewPrice values using subquery, therefore, you can not use cast with orderby for a computed column in the same query. The simplest way could be like below.

**Solution 1**

```
select * from (
Select top 100 ma.*,
               (Select Top (1) Price from [dbo].[ItemSKU] Where ma.OldSku = NewSKu) as NewPrice
from [dbo].[2018] as ma
)a order by cast(NewPrice as decimal(10,2)) desc
```

**Solution 2**

```
Select top 100 ma.*,
               cast((Select Top (1) Price from [dbo].[ItemSKU] Where ma.OldSku = NewSKu)as decimal(10,2)) as NewPrice
from [dbo].[2018] as ma
order by NewPrice desc
```

Comment: There aren't any aggregate functions here so I'm not sure what you're trying to point out (aggregate functions are the functions used with `GROUP BY` or windowing to combine values from multiple rows)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Agree that was my mistake. It is not an aggregate function.